Neovim help setting a variable
I use Neovim 0.10.0 with Ubuntu. Just started and try to set a variable for gitgutter_sign_modified.  In the readme it says to add in ~/.vimrc:
let g:gitgutter_sign_added = 'xx'
let g:gitgutter_sign_modified = 'yy'
let g:gitgutter_sign_removed = 'zz'
let g:gitgutter_sign_removed_first_line = '^^'
let g:gitgutter_sign_removed_above_and_below = '{'
let g:gitgutter_sign_modified_removed = 'ww'

but dont know how to do with Neovim. I use init.lua and tried this
vim.cmd([[
  let g:gitgutter_sign_modified = '*'
]])

but nothing changed.

In Lua I would do:
vim.g.gitgutter_sign_added = 'xx'
vim.g.gitgutter_sign_modified = 'yy'
vim.g.gitgutter_sign_removed = 'zz'
vim.g.gitgutter_sign_removed_first_line = '^^'
vim.g.gitgutter_sign_removed_above_and_below = '{'
vim.g.gitgutter_sign_modified_removed = 'ww'

More information about how the equivalence between the Vim scope and the Neovim lua API in: lua-guide-variables

Do we have a canonical "How do I access scoped variables (g:, w:, b:) in Neovim?" A help reference would also be good

I did in ~/.config/nvim/init.lua but the sign did not changed when  adding or deleting or modifing a line.  I also tried in the file gitgutter.lua (between config=function().. end,) and placed inside what you suggested; but not working.

I suspect another script is changing the same variables. Could you give us the output of the following command: :echo g:gitgutter_sign_added?

xx but in my php file it is +

Do you mean that when you open a php file the result of :echo g:gitgutter_sign_added is +-?

No the command :echo give xx but in the gutter the sign is +
